# What is the "System" repository shown in the output of "dnf info"?

Tags: dnf

I'm brushing up my knowledge of DNF and stumbled upon something I can't figure out. The output of `dnf info` often shows that a package belongs to the "System" repository:

```
$ dnf info zip | grep -E ^"Repository|From repo"
Repository   : @System
From repo    : anaconda
```

I know that "anaconda" means that the package was installed by the Anaconda installer. What I can't get me head round is the "System" repository. I got four enabled repositories, and "System" isn't one of them:

```
$ dnf repolist --enabled
repo id                          repo name
appstream                        AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream
baseos                           AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS
extras                           AlmaLinux 8 - Extras
powertools                       AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools
```

I've also figured out that `dnf repoquery -i zip` shows the actual repository:

```
$ dnf repoquery -i zip | grep ^Repository
Repository   : baseos
```

So, why does the output of `dnf info` show that `zip` lives in a repo named "System"? Is "System" simply the same as "BaseOS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "`@System`" repository indicates the packages that you have installed not from any repos but from files on the disk [manually] via `dnf install package.rpm`.

There's also the "`@@commandline`" repo which is for packages installed via `rpm -i`.